# How to extract day, month and year from xslt in ItemStyle.xsl?

Tags: 2013, xslt, item-styles

I have created custom template for CQWP in ItemStyle.

My code for template is:

```
  <xsl:template name="CustomLofbergs" match="Row[@Style='CustomLofbergs']" mode="itemstyle">



    <div class="main">
    <div class="subDateText">
        <div class="subDate">
            <div class="day">
                13 //I want to display the date here
            </div>

            <div class="monthyear">

                    <div class="month">
                        05 // Display month here
                    </div>
                    <div class="year">
                    1990  // Display year here.
                    </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="subText">
            <div class="eventTile">
                    <xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
            <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="DisplayTitle">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetTitle">
            <xsl:with-param name="Title" select="@Title"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
  <div class="item link-item">
    <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallPresenceStatusIconTemplate"/>
    <a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}" title="{@LinkToolTip}">
      <xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams = 'True'">
        <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
          <xsl:value-of select="@OnClickForWebRendering"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams != 'True' and @OpenInNewWindow = 'True'">
        <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
          <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$OnClickTargetAttribute"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="$DisplayTitle"/>
    </a>
  </div>                
            </div>
            <div class="eventDescription">
                <xsl:value-of select="@Description"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</xsl:template>
```

The template is for displaying events. So, I knew I have to use EventDate field but not having actual idea how to do..??

I used `<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(@EventDate,1033,'d')"/>` but not working for me.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:variable name="date" select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@EventDate), 1033, 1)"/>

<xsl:variable name="day" select="format-number(substring-before(substring-after($date,'/'),'/'),'00.')"/>
<xsl:variable name="month" select="format-number(substring-before($date,'/'),'00.')"/>
<xsl:variable name="year" select="format-number(substring(substring-after(substring-after($date,'/'),'/'),1,4),'00.')"/>


<!-- now you can use these variables in your code: -->

<div class="subDate">
    <div class="day">
         <xsl:value-of select="$day"/>
    </div>

    <div class="monthyear">
        <div class="month">
            <xsl:value-of select="$month"/>
        </div>
        <div class="year">
            <xsl:value-of select="$year"/>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

If you work with dates often in XSLT, I would also recommend you to have a look at this date library for SharePoint:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer-Components-PostAttachments/00-07-89-73-70/date_5F00_templates.xsl

(this is from Andy Lewis's post [Filtering and formatting with Date Values](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdesigner/archive/2008/02/25/filtering-and-formatting-with-date-values.aspx))

The library includes great amount of various useful templates: calculating amount of days between dates, formatting dates, etc. I used it myself many times and find the library quite reliable and comprehensive.

P.S. Btw, in SharePoint 2013, I would try to avoid using XSLT. There is CSWP and there is CSR... I'm not saying that you must drop your work and go learn these new things - no, but at least start exploring them would be a good idea ;)...